# Setup Automation - Firefox and Addons

Tags: command-line, scripting, firefox

I am improving my setup script for new installs and want it to include setting up firefox.

One big problem I found is, that it is not possible to install addons via CLI that automatically get updated by firefox.

My findings for anyone also searching:

- The `-install-global-extension` flag does not exist anymore in the current firefox installations
- It is possible to install the extensions manually by downloading the .xpi files and placing them in local or global extension directory. Scripts like [this](https://gist.github.com/eddiejaoude/0076739fe610189581d0) or [this](https://bernaerts.dyndns.org/linux/74-ubuntu/271-ubuntu-firefox-thunderbird-addon-commandline) are a good inspiration that I got to work after a bit of modification. Problem is that those installation do not get updated automatically (as the file is downloaded once and only loaded) and the user can not update or uninstall the extension at all. Meaning I have to periodically check if a new version of a addon exists (which I did not found a easy way as the filenames are unpredictable and there is no link to "the latest xpi file" for a given extension)
- Lastely, policy templates [(see here)](https://github.com/mozilla/policy-templates/blob/master/README.md#extensions) have the same problem as the xpi download and unpacking regarding updateing

Is there really no solution that basically tells/sets a config in firefox to install extensions and addons, the same as if the user clicks through the GUI?
It seems to me that this is a regular need for sysadmins and specifically the linux community wrt automation and CLI configuration.

Can anybody share their solution for this?

Comment: Is this for new installation to be used by _you_ and your own user profile or for systems to be used by others? How do you expect to interact with Firefox's user profile and account sync which includes addons?

Comment: I am quite flexible in this regard, what works best. The idea is that it can be updated without administrative input. As the normal user does not have su rights and can therefore not update the global extension folder I guess it should be easier to do it local. Afaik sync is not necessary for addons and I personally do neither use profiles nor sync. One idea I had is letting firefox config script run after I run ```adduser ```, configuring this account with the addons.

Comment: Have you thought about making FF profile part of `/etc/skel`?